# C-Prog Code::Blocks -- math.h library not linking within IDE ... works fine in command line. Where is the file/folder to link in IDE?

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, linux-mint

NEWB here:  Using Linux Mint 20.x - Code::Blocks - GCC --- I got this code to work on command line.  It wasn't working until I linked the math library using <-lm>  I'm trying to link math library in Code::Blocks to run code within IDE.  I can't find the library folder/file to link within Code::Blocks.

SideNote:  I added sqrt just to test the math.  sqrt works in IDE yet floor and ceil don't.  Seemed bizarre to me that some math.h functions work and others do not.

```
gcc tut36.c -o tut36 -lm
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

double bacon1 = 9.65345;
double bacon2 = 3.3;


printf("bacon1 is %.2lf\n", floor(bacon1));
printf("bacon2 is %.2lf\n", floor(bacon2));

printf("bacon1 is %.2lf\n", ceil(bacon1));
printf("bacon2 is %.2lf\n", ceil(bacon2));


int year1;
int year2;
int age;

printf("Enter a year\n");
scanf(" %d", &year1);

printf("Enter another year\n");
scanf(" %d", &year2);

age = year1 - year2;
age = abs(age);

printf("Your age is: %d %.0lf\n", age, sqrt(16));




return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution found:  in CODE::BLOCKS .... -lm  must be inserted into the compiler settings.   Settings -> Compiler -> Linker settings (tab) -> other linker options -> -lm

-lm evidently links the math library to the project.  Not sure why this is necessary if the math library is part of the standard library, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps shown in the image

[Click on Settings from start menu and then click on Compiler...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8z2k.png)

[Click on Linker settings tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdPkl.png)

[Click on Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJA2i.png)

[Type m on the box and click on ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKBfY.png)

[Now click on ok on the bottom right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAhp9.png)

And you are done!
Now you can compile any code with math.h header
Thank you!

Comment: Image based answers are less than ideal... better to include the steps within your answer with pictures as supplemental info, in case the pictures are unreachable